# Wordpress Enqueue style not working

Tags: php, wordpress, function, hyperlink

I'm making a custom wordpress theme, but for some reason the enqueue style is not working.

I've added:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

to the index.php

And i've added

```
<?php wp_head();?>
```

Inside the
head tag.

The following code is inside my functions.php:

```
function pompier_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-style', get_template_directory_uri() .    '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '1.0.0', false );


  //wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', false );


}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pompier_scripts' );
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: The code is correct, I mean you did not make the common mistakes. But at first check the view source if the css tags has been added or not. If not check your files are in right place. And before all of this be sure the get_header() is loading that desired file where you put wp_head()

Comment: First you have to check either your stylesheet has been attached or not...You can check it by view source....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but I just created my first child theme, and because It's based on a parent theme, I had to enqueue my custom stylesheet like this in order to make it work:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/style.css' );
```